# Why is there a diffrence in using for(var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) and for(var i = 3; i--;) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why is there a big diffrence in using for loop with and without constraints.

With condition
`for(var i = 3; i >= 0; i--) { console.log(i); }`

outputs
3
2
1
0

Without condition
`for(var i = 3; i--;) { console.log(i); }`

outputs
2
1
0

Why does the one without condition skip the first iteration and also stop at 0.

If you use no condition but add one instead of subtract it will result in an infinite loop

Comment: The condition (the middle part of `for (..; ..; ..)`) is executed *once before each iteration* to check whether the iteration should be executed. … This should explain the behaviour…!?

Comment: The difference in behavior between the two examples you provided is due to how the condition in the for loop is evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one **does** have a condition: `i--`. The modification to `i` in the condition is a side effect.

The condition runs before the log statement (instead of after it) so it doesn’t log `3` because `i` changed too soon.

`0` is a false value so when `i--` evaluates as `0` the condition no longer matches.

Comment: It's kind of implied but it is also the reason why adding results in an infinite loop. It will never reach 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

In your case, the final-expression is not used.
The condition is `i--` and it will stop when this is falsy, which means when `i-- = 0`

And the condition is executed every time before each itteration. Thus skipping 3.